# How to use Gin-gonic middleware with Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, web, go, go-gin

I'm using Gin-Gonic on a Google App Engine platform for my website.
Everything works fine but I'm starting to need to use some middleware.

When I try to use :

```
router.Use(MyMiddleware())
```

The middleware returned by `MyMiddleware()` doesn't seem to be run.

So my questions are :

- Is it possible to use gin-gonic middlewares when working with GAE ?
- If so, how can I achieve it ?

Thank you !

Here are my sources :

main.go :

```
func init() {
    router := routes.Router()

    // Set the config to the context
    router.Use(SetConfiguration())

    http.Handle("/", router)
}

func SetConfiguration() gin.HandlerFunc {
    configuration := config.GetConfiguration()

    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Set("config", configuration)
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

PS : `routes.Router()` simply set a router with `gin.New()` and add some routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middleware route should be the first to be added before the other routes. See this file from a project of mine where I use **CORS Middleware** and **Auth Middleware**

https://github.com/wilsontamarozzi/panda-api/blob/master/routers/router.go

Comment: Hey what a mistake ! Guess what, I just found out this when reading the Gin code and went here to answer myself. Thank you a lot for your answer !

I think this thing should be documented better...